# Docker bind mount directory vs named volume performance comparison

Tags: docker, containers

Is there any performance difference between following docker named volumes vs bind mounted volumes? If yes, how much numbers are we talking about?

1. Docker volume example:

```
docker run -v mysql:/var/lib/mysql mysql:tag
```

2. Docker bind mount example:

```
docker run -v /path/to/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql mysql:tag
```

These containers are used for mostly databases like elasticsearch, mysql and mongodb. Which one should I prefer?

Comment: afaik there's no difference. Obviously if the mapped folder on the host is local.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On a couple of platforms ([MacOS](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/#known-issues), [Windows with WSL 2](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/#best-practices)) bind mounts are known to be especially slow.

Beyond that, you shouldn't see a perceptible performance difference between named volumes, the container filesystem, files in the image (regardless of the number of layers), or bind mounts (particularly on native Linux).

A good general rule might be to use bind mounts for config files and log files, where I/O is relatively rare but you as a human need to access the files directly; named volumes for database storage and other content where I/O is relatively frequent but as a human you can't directly read the files; and the image itself for your application code.

Comment: I'm definitely not an expert, but that Windows link seems to be making recommendations about *where* to bind mount rather than comparing bind mounts and volumes, specifically recommending bind mounting to another Linux container instead of the Windows file system.

Comment: Why would WSL 2 be slow (assuming that the bind mount is in the Linux file system and not the Windows file system)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows there is a big performance hit if you set bind mounts on the Windows file system and not on the WSL file system:

docker run -v **\wsl$<DistroName>**\path\to\mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql mysql:tag

> "We recommend against working across operating systems with your
> files, ..... For the fastest performance speed, store your files in
> the WSL file system if you are working in a Linux..."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment?source=recommendations

> "Files can be accessed across the operating systems, but it may
> significantly slow down performance."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment?source=recommendations#file-storage